# Copy and paste on any device

Tags: clipboard

I find myself most of the time needing to copy a piece of text or even a link from my mobile and paste later (when I get out of the bathroom) on my PC.

Do you have the same problem? What are you using to solve this?

Regards,

Comment: Evernote but your question is off topic on SO...

Comment: Copy the text paste it to evernote (after login) go to your pc open the evernote app copy the text and paste it there. To long, I don't need the extra fancy video and voice share all I need is copy a piece of text and paste it over to my other device

Comment: I just have ir open everywhere at all time.

Answer (score 1):

I use [MyPhoneDesktop](http://www.myphonedesktop.com/)
for this. From their product description:

> With myPhoneDesktop, you can send content quickly from your desktop to your iPhone. Whether you want to send a long Google Map URL to a friend, or some text to a business colleague, or a photo to iPhone, myPhoneDesktop makes it easy.
>
> myPhoneDesktop makes your iPhone an extension of your desktop by making them work seamlessly together. **If you can copy it, you can send it to the iPhone.** Using the comfort of your Mac or PC full keyboard, you can send SMS messages, notes, or anything you can type. And in moments, it will be on your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch.

Just a satisfied user, not affiliated in any way.

Comment: Sorry, it does not do it for me, I have an android. I don't want to install a 138Mb + java jdk application on my Ubuntu for just copy and pasting text !